# How to obtain request / session / servletcontext attribute in JSP using EL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I know this isn't hard, but I'm not having any luck.

I want to make `fooList` from a Servlet available in a JSP.  So in the Servlet I have:

```
request.setAttribute("list", fooList);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/myJsp.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Then in the JSP, I want:

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${SOME_EL_HERE}">
    <!-- stuff -->
</c:forEach>
```

Where `SOME_EL_HERE` is an expression that retrieves the attribute that I have set on the `request`.

Any thoughts?  My preference is to not complicate a simple task by adding a framework, but I'm open to changes in strategy.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's just the attribute **name** as you've set yourself here:

```
request.setAttribute("list", fooList);
```

It's thus `"list"`:

```
${list}
```

This works the same way for `session.setAttribute("name", value)` and `application.setAttribute("name", value)`. The value is in EL available by just `${name}`.

---

More detail: EL uses by default [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) which scans in subsequently the page, request, session and application scopes for the firstnext non-null attribute value matching the given attribute name.

If you'd like to explicitly specify the scope for the case that you've multiple attributes with the same name in different scopes, then normal approach is to use `${pageScope}`, `${requestScope}`, `${sessionScope}` or `${applicationScope}`. E.g.

```
${requestScope.list}
```

#### See also:

- [Unified expression language in Java EE 5 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)

Comment: Hmm, not only is that easier than ${pageContext.request.attribute.list}, but it works, too.  Thanks much.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a bit more detail so that you at least understand what it is doing under the covers :)