# How do I add .jsp headers and footers to my Spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, web-applications, spring-mvc

How do I add .jsp headers and footers to my Spring MVC web app?

I know there's many different answers, but I would like to know (them all really but more importantly) **what is the proper way to do this?** I'm just learning Spring and I have a hint the answer lies with HandlerInterceptor. For now, I might just do so .jsp includes. Even with this include solution, could you detail where I would place the headers/footers structurally? Any advice or direction would be great.

Answer (score 9):

I found your question whilst researching :-) Not sure if my solution is `<good | bad | a hack | already exists>` or if there is a better way but it's working for my current project.

In your `myapp-servlet.xml` you can extend the viewResolver *viewClass* with your own implementation:

#### myapp-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:viewClass="com.my.app.view.JstlView"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
  p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

By overriding the renderMergedOutputModel you can force all *views* to really be a template in which you can define your global layout and then simply `<jsp:include/>` your partial(s).

#### JstlView.java

```
package com.my.app.view;

import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JstlView extends InternalResourceView {
    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String dispatcherPath = prepareForRendering(request, response);

        // set original view being asked for as a request parameter
        request.setAttribute("partial", dispatcherPath.substring(dispatcherPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        // force everything to be template.jsp
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

If you look Spring's [InternalResourceView.java](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.java?format=ok) you'll get a better idea of what Spring is doing when determining what view to use.

#### template.jsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <header>
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
    </header>
    <jsp:include page="${partial}"/>
    <footer>
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[How to obtain request / session / servletcontext attribute in JSP using EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579172/637889) helped me here with getting the attribute value `${partial}` out.

#### simple_partial.jsp

```
<p>I'm a partial!</p>
```

Then in a controller, return the `simple_partial` view

#### App.java

```
package com.my.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class App{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "simple_partial";
    }
}
```

which will get wrapped by the `template.jsp` and responded out.

Comment: clean and simple answer. But what if we want to add some exceptions to it? Say I want to have a **login.jsp** page without the header/footer, how can we reach that?
And I think there's another issue. If we want a partial with some dynamic content passed through ModelAndView, they will not take effect, i.e., in the call stack Controller > Partial > ViewResolver, the data inside the model will be passed into the ViewResolver and reach the template and not the partial view. I do not know if I was clear, but I tried.

Comment: Good questions. It's been a while since I wrote this and I can't exactly remember what I did. I think I used `rd.forward(requestToExpose, getRequestToExpose(request))` in the `JstlView` to forward onto another resource. You can also get the path for the request dispatcher with `prepareForRendering(getRequestToExpose(request), response)`. I believe that an `@ResponseBody` annotated method that does `return new ModelAndView(partial, model, modelObject)` *was* correctly reaching the partial. I probably used `exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(model, requestToExpose)` in my `renderMergedOutputModel`

Comment: I'll try to find some of the code and edit my answer later.

Comment: are there any updates on this? im also in the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [SiteMesh](http://www.sitemesh.org/) first and [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) second.

Comment: Any answers not using other people's code? For now I do a simple include for a header and footer.

Comment: Then that's your answer.  You don't need anything else from this site.

Comment: thank you, but my question was much beyond where I was already at. For anyone else reading this, I would still appreciate any input or elaboration.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the links I provided.  Even if you don't want to use "other people's code", you can get insight into how they thought about it.