# Spring controller @RequestMapping for Included JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Through out my site, all jsp pages include bodyHeader.jsp. I have to query db to populate some fields on bodyHeader.jsp. I mapped the header jsp in my controller, i do NOT want this method to be triggered on every  page. Well this method is not be called, what I am missing?

In very jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="/fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
```

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fragments/bodyHeader", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCategoryList(Model aaModel) {

    aaModel.addAttribute("categories", this.caService.findCategoryByLevel(0));
}
```

Comment: Please add your viewresolver definition

Answer (score 2):

For building page layout I recommend using Apache Tiles. The pages will be assembled from fragments at runtime.

To use Apache Tiles you can add `TilesViewResolver` as Spring component:

```
...
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
...
```

and also `TilesConfigurer`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property>
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Tiles template `views.xml`:

```
...
<tiles-definition>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB_INF/views/common_template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB_INF/views/tiles/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="side" value="/WEB_INF/views/tiles/side.jsp"/>
        ...
    </definition>
    <definition name="main" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

See Also:

- [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)
- [Is including other JSP via the Spring MVC framework a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604033/is-including-other-jsp-via-the-spring-mvc-framework-a-good-idea)
- [Templates in a Spring MVC web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347181/templates-in-a-spring-mvc-web-application)
- [How do I add .jsp headers and footers to my Spring MVC web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405697/how-do-i-add-jsp-headers-and-footers-to-my-spring-mvc-web-app)