# How to display data in struts form if object has another object

Tags: struts, struts-1

I'm working on struts 1.3 framework application.
I have one object which I'm setting in request attribute.

```
request.setAttribute("school",school);
```

And I'm trying to display that object through `<bean:define>` tag.

E.g.
     School is Value Object

```
School school;
```

in school VO object I have another two object

```
Student student;
Teacher teacher;
```

And I'm trying to display value of student as well as teacher object

`<bean:define id="summary" name="school" />

<bean:define id="StudentSummary" name="summary" property="student"/>

<bean:define id="TeacherSummary" name="summary" property="teacher"/>`

And writing this element through  tag

`<bean:write name="StudentSummary" property="name" />

    <bean:write name="StudentSummary" property="class" />

    <bean:write name="TeacherSummary" property="name" />`

But it is giving
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find message resources under key org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE

what would be wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never done it using bean tag but you can do it using Expression language(EL). EL, I believe is a more standard way to do things.

Take a look at this previous post. I think it helps [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579172/how-to-obtain-request-attribute-in-jsp-using-el)

I think in your case you can do something along the line of

`<c:out value="${school.student.name}"/>`

The above statement will print the value of "name", if you have a "name" property in your student object.