# how to inject userContext in JSP pages

Tags: spring-mvc, localization

how do I retrieve the values of a context in a jsp file? this tutorial is perfect for what I need but I need to retrieve the property values in the jsp file.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-listfactorybean-example/

is there a specific interceptor that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Inject your bean (or source) of `userContext` into your controller, so you have access to it in a local variable.

So taking the example maybe this is:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerBean customerBean;

@RequestMapping(value="/foobar/index.jsp")
public String (HttpServletRequest request) {
Object userContext = customerBean.getLists();
request.setAttribute("userContext", userContext);
return "/foobar/index.jsp";  // expecting JstlView viewResolver to map to JSP file
}
```

In the CONTROLLER simply add data to the HttpServletRequest (which you just add as argument to the method to introduce it).

Then use `request.setAttribute("userContext", userContext);` then in JSP simply access it using Expression Language like `${userContext}`.  There are other ways using Spring model paradigm but they effectively do the above.

Ensure you have your JstlView setup to https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-spring-controller

More info about how to use EL in JSPs to retrieve data attached to request:
[How to obtain request / session / servletcontext attribute in JSP using EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579172/how-to-obtain-request-attribute-in-jsp-using-el)

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to spring context right?

In general, JSPs should be a template of a page only, so the only interaction with the back-end should be accessing the values of the scoped attributes. This means that whichever bean value you need you should instead store in the model.

This being said, there are a few ways you can expose spring beans to view. Depends on which View resolver you're using, the ones that extend `UrlBasedViewResolver` have the [`setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html#setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes-boolean-) property

> Set whether to make all Spring beans in the application context
>   accessible as request attributes, through lazy checking once an
>   attribute gets accessed. This will make all such beans accessible in
>   plain ${...} expressions in a JSP 2.0 page, as well as in JSTL's c:out
>   value expressions.
>
> Default is "false".

You would configure it like

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```